# Dependence placed on C/C++ operator precedence; operators '&&' and '==' [MISRA 2012 Rule 12.1, advisory] | pclint 9050

Tags: c, misra, pc-lint

```
uint8 config;    
#define ELEM1 1U

void test1(void)
{
    /*Check Bit 0 of Configuration*/
    if((config) == 2 && (config) == 4)
    {
        arr[ELEM1].status[0]          = 0x00;
    }

}
```

do I need to try with

1)

```
if(((config) == 2) && ((config) == 4))
```

2. 

```
if((Boolean)((config) == 2) && ((config) == 4))
```

after above change, I am observing error now:

> Conditional expression should have essentially Boolean type [MISRA
> 2012 Rule 14.4, required]

Comment: `(config)` is useless. Why use parentheses around a single variable?

Comment: "Check Bit 0" - but you test `2` and `4` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `config` can't realistically have the value `2` and `4` at once, now can it? So you probably meant to use `||`. Or bitwise `&` perhaps?

As for the warning, if you mix several operators in the same expression, MISRA-C requires that you add parenthesis around sub expressions. The MISRA compliant code would be:

```
if( (config==2) || (config==4) )
```

The result of `&& ||` etc operators is essentially boolean, so there is no need to cast.